# how to use nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, csv, email, dictionary

I am trying to write some code with the Hunter.io API to automate some of my b2b email scraping. It's been a long time since I've written any code and I could use some input. I have a CSV file of Urls, and I want to call a function on each URL that outputs a dictionary like this:

```
`{'domain': 'fromthebachrow.com', 'webmail': False, 'pattern': '{f}{last}', 'organization': None, 'emails': [{'value': 'fbach@fromthebachrow.com', 'type': 'personal', 'confidence': 91, 'sources': [{'domain': 'fromthebachrow.com', 'uri': 'http://fromthebachrow.com/contact', 'extracted_on': '2017-07-01'}], 'first_name': None, 'last_name': None, 'position': None, 'linkedin': None, 'twitter': None, 'phone_number': None}]}`
```

for each URL I call my function on. I want my code to return just the email address for each key labeled 'value'.

Value is a key that is contained in a list that itself is an element of the directory my function outputs. I am able to access the output dictionary to grab the list that is keyed to 'emails', but I don't know how to access the dictionary contained in the list. I want my code to return the value in that dictionary that is keyed with 'value', and I want it to do so for all of my urls.

```
from pyhunyrt import PyHunter  
import csv  
file=open('urls.csv')  
reader=cvs.reader (file)  
urls=list(reader)  
hunter=PyHunter('API Key')  
for item in urls:      
 output=hunter.domain_search(item)
 output['emails'`
```

which returns a list that looks like this for each item:

```
 [{
    'value': 'fbach@fromthebachrow.com',
    'type': 'personal',
    'confidence': 91,
    'sources': [{
      'domain': 'fromthebachrow.com',
      'uri': 'http://fromthebachrow.com/contact',
      'extracted_on': '2017-07-01'
    }], 
    'first_name': None,
    'last_name': None,
    'position': None,
    'linkedin': None, 
    'twitter': None,
    'phone_number': None
  }]
```

How do I grab the first dictionary in that list and then access the email paired with 'value' so that my output is just an email address for each url I input initially?

Answer (score 1):

To grab the first dict (or any item) in a list, use `list[0]`, then to grab a value of a key `value` use `["value"]`. To combine it, you should use `list[0]["value"]`